# How to Integrate a project into another one?

Tags: android

I have a file share app where I want to integrate mobile_vision_text_recognizer_scan app in to that. I am getting error in scan_app manifest file and I am not able to call scan_app in to file share app

Comment: explain in detail with error log

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.OcrCaptureActivity">

Comment: above activity is in scan_app manifest file and that activity name was not recognizing and showing in red color

Answer (score 0):

In file setting.gradle:

```
include ':core'
project(':core').projectDir = new File("Link project want integrate") // ex: E:\IFS\Andorid\VpbsCore
```

In module app build.gradle:

```
  compile project(path: ':core')
```

Or you can import module with project want integrate.